# Unrecognised tag: 'dependecies' with maven in pom.xml

Tags: maven, dependencies

I get an error while running mvn compile and can't seem to find the error in the synthax. I get this error :

Malformed POM ../pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'dependecies' (position: START_TAG seen ...</repositories> \n\n    <dependecies>... @19:18)  @ ../pom.xml, line 19, column 18 -> [Help 2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ch.myStartup.myFirstProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
                <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 

    <dependecies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.freenet-mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>mantissa</artifactId>
            <version>v0.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>simple-upload</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-upload</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/simple-upload-0.3.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bcel/bcel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfree/jfreechart -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ca.umontreal.iro.simul/ssj -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.umontreal.iro.simul</groupId>
            <artifactId>ssj</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/fop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jogl-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.13</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/colt/colt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>colt</groupId>
            <artifactId>colt</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.vecmath/vecmath -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.vecmath</groupId>
            <artifactId>vecmath</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluegen-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/batik-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.16</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependecies>
</project>
```

I tried moving the dependencies in different places but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Take a deep look at how `dependecies` is exactly written... it should be `dependencies` there is missing `n` before the `cies`...

Comment: There is a typo in the <dependencies> tag

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I checked ! Must be my sight... Anyways, thanks a lot !